# Support+ MFA Issue

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

We’re trying to configure MFA to secure the accounts used for a Support+ service. On their end they need to see the option to “Configure app without notifications” as shown in the screenshot below. We believed this option was managed by enabling the method “verification code from mobile app or hardware token” which I have verified is enabled according to step 4 of these instructions "https://lazyadmin.nl/office-365/how-to-setup-mfa-in-office-365/", but the option is still not available for the support+service when we enable MFA on the accounts.

Could you please help look into what needs to be configured to make this option available?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umlai.png)

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce in my environment I am getting the same result***:

[image]

According to my knowledge Microsoft azure portal as updated authenticator method when u click on **Configure app without notification** it will just generate a new different QR code instead of you can set up different methods like below.

[image]

[image]